# Mysql python connector - Row returning null

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to make a very simple select using mysql connector , however , when i try to execute the following commands , the row always returns null , even if there is data to be selected

```
self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='123qwe', host='192.168.56.1', database='teste')
        self.cursor = self.cnx
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
        self.query = ("SELECT cod_produto,quantidade FROM itens_comanda WHERE cod_comanda = %s AND cod_produto = %s")
        self.query_data = (comanda,item)
        self.cursor.execute(self.query,self.query_data)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            return [False,0,0]
        else:
            for i in row:
                return [True,i[0],i[1]]
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing your password and host first ;)

Comment: We cannot run this code to replicate your problem. Perhaps you could post an example we can replicate? Also, are you using `mysql.connector`?